# $ \frac{1}{a^{2} + b^{2} + 1} + \frac{1}{b^{2}+c^{2}+1} + \frac{1}{c^{2} + a^{2} + 1} \ge 1 $, prove $ab + bc + ca \le 3$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

If $a,b,c$ real numbers such that $$ \frac{1}{a^{2} + b^{2} + 1} + \frac{1}{b^{2}+c^{2}+1} + \frac{1}{c^{2} + a^{2} + 1} \ge 1 $$,  prove that $ab + bc + ca \le 3$.

---

**Attempt:**

Assume that $a,b,c > 0$.

$$ \frac{1}{a^{2} + b^{2} + 1} + \frac{1}{b^{2}+c^{2}+1} + \frac{1}{c^{2} + a^{2} + 1} \ge 1  $$
$$ \implies  (a^{2} + b^{2} + 1)(b^{2}+c^{2}+1) + (a^{2} + b^{2} + 1)(a^{2}+c^{2}+1) +  (a^{2} + c^{2} + 1)(b^{2}+c^{2}+1) \ge (a^{2} + b^{2} + 1)(b^{2}+c^{2}+1)(c^{2} + a^{2} + 1)$$

$$ \implies  ((ab)^{2} + (ac)^{2} + (bc)^{2} + a^{2} + 2 b^{2} + c^{2} + b^{4} + 1) + ((ab)^{2} + (ac)^{2} + (bc)^{2} + b^{2} + 2 a^{2} + c^{2} + a^{4} + 1) + ((ab)^{2} + (ac)^{2} + (bc)^{2} + a^{2} + 2 c^{2} + b^{2} + c^{4} + 1) \ge (a^{2} + b^{2} + 1)(b^{2}+c^{2}+1)(c^{2} + a^{2} + 1)$$

$$ \implies  3((ab)^{2} + (ac)^{2} + (bc)^{2}) + 4(a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2}) + (a^{4}+b^{4}+c^{4}) + 3  \ge (a^{2} + b^{2} + 1)(b^{2}+c^{2}+1)(c^{2} + a^{2} + 1)$$

Next, notice

$$(a^{2} + b^{2} + 1)(b^{2}+c^{2}+1)(c^{2} + a^{2} + 1) = ((ab)^{2} + (ac)^{2} + (bc)^{2} + a^{2} + 2 b^{2} + c^{2} + b^{4} + 1)(c^{2} + a^{2} + 1) $$
$$ = (abc)^{2} + a^{2}c^{4} + b^{2}c^{4} + (ac)^{2} + 2(bc)^{2} + c^{4} + b^{4}c^{2} + c^{2} + a^{4} b^{2} + a^{4}c^{2} + (abc)^{2} + a^{4}  + 2(ab)^{2} + (ac)^{2} + b^{4}a^{2} + a^{2} +  (ab)^{2} + (ac)^{2} + (bc)^{2} + a^{2} + 2 b^{2} + c^{2} + b^{4} + 1 $$
$$ = 2(abc)^{2} + 3(ac)^{2} + 3(bc)^{2} + 3(ab)^{2} + c^{4}a^{2} + c^{4} b^{2} + b^{4}a^{2} + b^{4} c^{2} + a^{4}b^{2} + a^{4} c^{2} + a^{4} + b^{4} + c^{4} + 2(a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2}) + 1  $$

So we have 
$$ \frac{1}{a^{2} + b^{2} + 1} + \frac{1}{b^{2}+c^{2}+1} + \frac{1}{c^{2} + a^{2} + 1} \ge 1 $$
$$ \implies  2(a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2}) +  3  \ge 2(abc)^{2}  + c^{4}a^{2} + c^{4} b^{2} + b^{4}a^{2} + b^{4} c^{2} + a^{4}b^{2} + a^{4} c^{2} + 1 $$

Comment: I think  $ab+bc+ac\leq 3$ comes from adding $3$ inequalities together, probably some $A-G$ or $A-K$ inequalities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it can be proved by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Here is my approach:
Observe that 
$$ \frac{1+1+c^2}{(a^2+b^2+1)(1+1+c^2)}=\frac{1}{(a^2+b^2+1)}  $$
and by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have 
$$ \frac{2+c^2}{(a+b+c)^2}\geq \frac{1+1+c^2}{(a^2+b^2+1)(1+1+c^2)}=\frac{1}{(a^2+b^2+1)}.  $$
Thus, we have 
$$ 6+a^2+b^2+c^2\geq (a+b+c)^2 $$
which leads 
$$ ab+bc+ca\leq 3.$$